# How can to use fn:contains case-insensitive in JSL EL?

Tags: jsf, el, contains, uppercase, lowercase

I trying to find out if one string contains another. But, unfortunately, `fn:contains` function is case-sensitive. Are there are any ways to make it case-insensitive?

I tried to put both into one case:

```
fn:contains(car.color.toLowerCase(), smartBean.txt.toLowerCase()) ? 'true' : 'false'
```

But it didn't work due to method's brackets. I also can't use `f:to-upper` inside `f:contains` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`fn:containsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/containsIgnoreCase.fn.html). Just use it instead.

```html
#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(car.color, smartBean.txt)}
```

By the way, your failed `toLowerCase()` attempt should have been done as follows:

```html
#{fn:contains(fn:toLowerCase(car.color), fn:toLowerCase(smartBean.txt))}
```

Using `toUpperCase()` works as good as well:

```html
#{fn:contains(fn:toUpperCase(car.color), fn:toUpperCase(smartBean.txt))}
```

Perhaps you just made an EL syntax error.

Note that the `? 'true' : 'false'` part is completely superfluous as that's already returned by the function.

Answer (score 1):

For those just finding this, @BalusC's answer is correct - but structure has changed, see just fn:upper-case, fn:lower-case - don't see the ignoreCase option anymore but if you cast it one way or the other to compare, it will work.